# Are customs still important to follow and why?

Tags: customs

We have many customs and traditions to follow in hinduism, but I see that many persons are not following or neglecting them.

For example Brahmins should not cross the ocean but that is already broke by many people including Swami Vivekananda. Like wise there are many traditions which are not getting followed either for personal reasons or with changing society.

Soon I think upper caste people will drop the tradition to do not non veg food.

All those who will not follow traditions will be punished?

I dont think a person can do anything these days if strictly follows those customs.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda was not a Brahmin

Comment: In Kali Yuga sin always dominates .. Adharma prevails .. that's the nature of the Yuga .. and that's why majority of the population don't follow religious customs now but that does not mean that customs are not to be followed.

Comment: You are getting social customs which vary by locality and time conflated with Santana Dharma. The vedas teach us to follow 'rtam' and 'satyam', 'right' and 'true'. Much of what you think as customs and traditions are elicited in the puranas and commentaries and are smriti, not sruti.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda was a sanyasin who had given up worldly life. On becoming a sanyasin he lost any caste he was born into. Crossing the seas does not impurify him because he had no caste anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for following some of these obsolete customs and traditions? Did Hindus follow these customs and traditions from the time of the Vedas? How do you explain the presence of non-Indian Hindus in Indonesia and its spread to Philippines in medieval times if no Brahmin could cross the seas? In fact there is no need to accept any custom and tradition if they violate reason.

**Attitude towards ancient custom**

> One should practice what one considers to be one’s duty, **guided by
> reasons, instead of blindly following the practices of the world**.

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII**

> However, **discard** the desire (kama) and material wealth (artha) if
> contrary to Dharma; as also, **any usage or custom or rules regarded as
> source of Dharma if at any time they were to lead to unhappiness or
> arouse people's indignation.**

**(Manu Smriti 4.176)**

**Importance of reason**

> The man of true knowledge should find for himself the morality laid
> down for the good. If even a wise man speaks of morality under the
> influence of wrath or confusion of understanding or ignorance, his
> deliverances go for nothing. **Discourses on morality made with the aid
> of an intelligence that is derived from the true letter and the spirit
> of the scriptures, are worthy of praise and not those which are made
> with the help of anything else. Even the words heard from an ignorant
> person, if in themselves they be fraught with sense, come to be
> regarded as pious and wise. In days of old, Usanas said unto the
> Daityas this truth, which should remove all doubts, that scriptures
> are no scriptures if they cannot stand the test of reason.**

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CXLII**

I would like to add that one's **conscience** (**self-satisfaction**) plays a great role in a Hindu's life and it's importance is accepted by Hindu scripture. If a Hindu after carefully reading scripture sees that his conscience can't accept what the scripture is saying then he is free to reject the scriptural statement.

> 6. The whole Veda is the (first) source of the sacred law, next the tradition and the virtuous conduct of those who know the (Veda
>    further), also the customs of holy men, and (finally)
>    **self-satisfaction**.
> 7. Whatever law has been ordained for any (person) by Manu, that has been fully declared in the Veda: for that (sage was) omniscient.
> 8. But a learned man after fully scrutinising all this with the eye of knowledge, should, in accordance with the authority of the revealed
>    texts, be intent on (the performance of) his duties.

**Manu Smriti II.6-8**

This principle is accepted by the Gita.

> "... Reflecting on this entire teaching **do as you think fit**.'

**Gita 18.63**

Even the Lord is giving people freedom to accept or reject His teaching.

I am shocked to see people opposing 'anti-scriptural statements' when the supremacy of one's conscience over scripture is an accepted principle in Hindu dharma. One shouldn't be slave to anything including scripture. The attempt being made here to nullify the teachings about conscience in the Gita and the Manu Smriti must be resolutely opposed. Some people seem to think that they are greater than the Lord.

Comment: "if no Brahmin could cross the seas?" not could should .. there are various sins mentioned in ancient scriptures so obviously from time immemorial violations of scriptural injunctions (Dharma) used to happen. So what is the big deal if some Brahmins crossed the sea? It only proves that some Brahmins did not follow religious injunctions but it does not prove that they are not to be followed..  Also it looks like you used these same set verses in more than 100 answers of yours to draw a particular conclusion

Comment: here is yet another - *do whatever your conscience tells you* - Lokayata/Charvaka post from this user. @Rickross - flag this answer for misleading new users cos he posts the same thing over and over again.

Comment: *"How do you explain the presence of non-Indian Hindus in Indonesia and its spread to Philippines in medieval times?"* - *"How do you explain the occurrence of murders if murder is illegal"* ? @user2225190

Comment: @mar I agree about the misleading part .. he just cherry picks to mislead and uses mostly a same set of verses without context to reach an anti scriptural view ..

Comment: All dharmas do not seem to span across yugas.(some are already eschewed as part of scriptures in kali age) In this case, (supposedly), Non acceptance of a brahmana after crossing seas could be an injunction meant for kali age only .Swami Vivekananda has risen above all worldly needs , so such a BrahmaJnani is not bound by any injunction. Still Swamiji contemplated, whether  to cross seas or not. If test of reason suffice, then shaastras are redundant. shaastras seem to guide on matters ,that are humanly imperceivable(adrishta)

Comment: Thereby any attitude  to escape shaastras under the pretext of , exceptions (meant to be excercised on an unavoidable circumstace that overweights demerits) could be detrimental, for the individuals spiritual progress. Still if one is not inclined /does not have faith over the astika path, (according to Gita) is free to subscribe spiritual path of nastika in nature as well. Invariably, authority to eschew an injunction  is vested in seers who can see the past present and future. (In my understanding )

Comment: Not agreeing with a particular scriptural verse does not always mean a Nastika stance.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay - correct, not always. but in your case, it does.

Comment: First high anxiety, then comment about same quotes and now finally a psychological profiling. Pathetic.

Answer (score 3):

Customs and traditions are the integral part of every Sanatani. This was never be classified under oppression or monopoly as viewed by alien lenses.

```
All those who will not follow traditions will be punished?
```

As per Dharma shastras, Yes!

Thus, coming to various shastra pramanas why one is ought to follow customs & traditions,

Vamana Purana, Chapter 15 Pulastya Maharishi explains this to Sukeshi.

> ....यो हापयति तस्यासौ परिकुप्यति भास्करः।।
> He mours the wrath of Surya, who forsakes the duties.

> कुपितः कुलनाशाय ईश्वरो रोगवृद्धये।
> भानुर्षे यतते तस्य नरस्य क्षणदाचर।।
> The offended Surya strives to destroy his family and subjects, him to increased diseases, O demon.

> तस्मात स्वधर्म न हि संत्यजेत न हापयेच्चापि हि नात्मवंशम्।
> यः संत्यजेच्चापि निजं हि धर्मं तस्मै प्रकृप्यते दिवाकरसतु।।
> Therefore one must never renounce his Dharma, nor should he bring the destruction of about his own family. On him Surya becomes angry who abandons his duties.

Gītā 1.40 says,

> कुलक्षये प्रणश्यन्ति कुलधर्माः सनातनाः।
> धर्मे नष्टे कुलं कृत्स्नमधर्मोऽभिभवत्युत।।
> In the destruction of a family, the immemorial religious rites of that family perish; on the destruction of spirituality, impiety, indeed, overcomes the whole family.

Kulaskhay, also means destruction of family traditions.
Now what are the outcomes of bringing end to family traditions are again said in Geeta.

> अधर्माभिभवात्कृष्ण प्रदुष्यन्ति कुलस्त्रिय: |
> स्त्रीषु दुष्टासु वार्ष्णेय जायते वर्णसङ्कर: ||
>  With the preponderance of vice, O Krishna, the women of the family become immoral; and from the immorality of women, O descendent of Vrishni, unwanted progeny are born.

> सङ्करो नरकायैव कुलघ्नानां कुलस्य च |
> पतन्ति पितरो ह्येषां लुप्तपिण्डोदकक्रिया:।।
> An increase in unwanted children results in hellish life both for the family and for those who destroy the family. Deprived of sacrificial offerings, the ancestors of such corrupt families also fall.

> दोषैरेतै: कुलघ्नानां वर्णसङ्करकारकै: |
> उत्साद्यन्ते जातिधर्मा: कुलधर्माश्च शाश्वता:।।
> Through the evil deeds of those who destroy the family tradition and thus give rise to unwanted progeny, a variety of social and family welfare activities are ruined.

> उत्सन्नकुलधर्माणां मनुष्याणां जनार्दन |
> नरकेऽनियतं वासो भवतीत्यनुशुश्रुम || 44||
> O Janardan (Krishna), I have heard from the learned that those who destroy family traditions dwell in hell for an indefinite period of time.

Well in some scripture, there was mentioned that Lakshmi devi deserts those places where, there are no traditions & duties followed. Where there are no festivites celebrated & where there are no sacrificing obulations offered to deities, and so on...

Thus, customs are indeed to be followed wisely.

```
I dont think a person can do anything these days if strictly follows those customs.
```

That's true as there are some customs which are too difficult to be followed either due to change of situations in current times or due to unsaid reasons. For an example, if the student gets an offer to learn abroad under scholarship, or supposed a diseased person can be treated overseas, thus as far as today's time is concerned no one will think about what scriptures says on going overseas.(might be the wrong examples to be put forth, but these are the most basic reasons why people tend to overlook shastras.)
Thus, Jagadguru Shankaracharya Sri Sri Bharati Tirtha Mahasannidhanam of Shrungeri math said this in one of this sermons,

> "If one unable to follow the customs & rules laid in scriptures, for them Bhagwan naam jaap is ultimate solution. They must take refugee in naam jaap, as it not only compensates for sins arising due to not following scriptures but, also opens the doors to liberation".
> (Those who can follow customs, they must definetly follow those as far as possible).

**कालिकार्पणमास्तु ।**